# How to select item from list with a value closest to another in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook which returns the below output:

```
ok: [Lab_Core_SW] => {
    "Test_List": [
        {
            "Firewall_IP": "10.120.193.100",
            "IP_Address": "10.120.0.0",
            "IP_and_Mask": "10.120.0.0/16",
            "Subnet_Mask": "16",
            "VRF_Name": "vrf1"
        },
        {
            "Firewall_IP": "10.120.160.36",
            "IP_Address": "10.120.46.0",
            "IP_and_Mask": "10.120.46.0/25",
            "Subnet_Mask": "25",
            "VRF_Name": "vrf2"
        },
        {
            "Firewall_IP": "10.120.187.68",
            "IP_Address": "10.120.0.0",
            "IP_and_Mask": "10.120.0.0/16",
            "Subnet_Mask": "16",
            "VRF_Name": "vrf3"
        },
        {
            "Firewall_IP": "10.109.1.66",
            "IP_Address": "10.0.0.0",
            "IP_and_Mask": "10.0.0.0/8",
            "Subnet_Mask": "8",
            "VRF_Name": "vrf4"
        },
        {
            "Firewall_IP": "10.120.184.68",
            "IP_Address": "10.120.0.0",
            "IP_and_Mask": "10.120.0.0/16",
            "Subnet_Mask": "16",
            "VRF_Name": "vrf5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way that I can take the Subnet_Mask of each item in the list and find the number closest to 32 and then only print that item in the list so I am left with the below:

```
        {
            "Firewall_IP": "10.120.160.36",
            "IP_Address": "10.120.46.0",
            "IP_and_Mask": "10.120.46.0/25",
            "Subnet_Mask": "25",
            "VRF_Name": "vrf2"
        }
```

I don't want to have to use `when: item.Subnet_Mask >= x` as this may either return more than one result or none depending on the routes on the core switch.

I have had a look at the ipaddr filter but it doesn't seem to have what I need.

I am aware of the lambda function in python but if it is possible to tie that in with ansible in any way I have been unable to find out how.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your exact use case, but you can extract an item from the list with an attribute that is closest to some other attribute by doing something like the below. Note that it's loading your output from a JSON file -- in your case, it's likely registered already.

**play.yaml:**

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    obj: "{{ lookup('file', 'list.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        diff: "{{ 32 - item['Subnet_Mask'] | int }}"
      loop: "{{ obj['Test_List'] }}"
      register: diff_result
    - set_fact:
        min_diff: "{{ diff_result.results | sort(attribute='ansible_facts.diff') | first }}"
    - debug:
        var: min_diff.item
```

This playbook loops over each item, subtracts the subnet mask from 32, sorts the results by the difference and outputs the item with the smallest difference.

**Run with:**

```
ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE=True ansible-playbook play.yaml -i 127.0.0.1,
```

The `ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE` is necessary to make sure `diff` is recorded as an integer instead of a string using `set_fact`.

**Output:**

```
TASK [debug]
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "min_diff.item": {
        "Firewall_IP": "10.120.160.36", 
        "IP_Address": "10.120.46.0", 
        "IP_and_Mask": "10.120.46.0/25", 
        "Subnet_Mask": "25", 
        "VRF_Name": "vrf2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me with this. What I was missing from my initial playbook was the ```ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE=True``` arguement after that everything worked as expected